# How to update keyword status,maxCPC and keyword text using google adwords api

Tags: google-ads-api

Can anyone tell me how to update the keyword status,keyword text and keyword maxCpc using google adwords api.I am trying the basic example i.e Update keyword but it is not working.

Please let me know the procedure to solve this problem !

Comment: @duskwuff I am also facing the same issue if you have found the solution, please do tell me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which language do you use, but I've used this C# code to modify keywords states through Google AdWords API:

```cs
public void SetKeywordState(long groupId, long keywordId, bool newState)     
{
    // Make sure your web.config contains correct data (developer token etc.)
    AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
    // 1st step - creation of criterion service.
    var criterionService = (AdGroupCriterionService)user
               .GetService(Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib.AdWordsService
                           .v201406.AdGroupCriterionService);
    // 2nd step - creation of AdGroupCriterion (keyword is criterion)       
    // and new state assignment
    var tgtKwrd = new BiddableAdGroupCriterion
                      {
                         adGroupId = groupId,
                         criterion = new Keyword { id = keywordId },
                         userStatus = newState ? UserStatus.ENABLED : UserStatus.PAUSED
                      };
    // 3rd step - creation of operation
    var co = new AdGroupCriterionOperation
                 {
                    @operator = Operator.SET,
                    operand = tgtKwrd
                 };
    // 4th step - commit keyword changes to Google.
    criterionService.mutate(new[] { co });
}
```

Modification of maxCPC and keywordText is going exactly in the same way.
Also, there are many useful [code examples](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries) in different languages. In this case I've used [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/CSharp/v201409/BasicOperations/UpdateKeyword.cs) code example from Google libraries. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

My Client Center -> Select your campaign -> Go to the keywords Tab -> Make changes as needed.

OPTIONAL:  try using the AdWords Editor. It is freely available for download. Though I wouldn't really recommend this as its for advanced users.

1) http://www.google.com/intl/en/adwordseditor/

Comment: This is through website.I am asking "Using google adwords API" how can we change these things.